# iOS: How to unistall a configuration profile programmatically

Tags: ios, profile, apn

I have a mobileconfig which is used to add APN into iphone, whereas it does work for iOS8/9/10, but not iOS11. In iOS11, it says "invalid profile". If install this mobileconfig again, it says "UUID is not unique".

Later on, I found out the main cause. It is because the "username" parameter is missing from APN key, so that the iOS11 claimed the profile installation is failed, but it did installed the value "ABCDE" into APN, and set as default APN value too. (clicking “reset” button in APN setting will figure out that it has been set to be default). However, from the setting>profile, I can see NO profile is yet installed, so I can't further install or reinstall another APN profile mobileconfig. The reason behind is that the existing one (hidden one) is not able to uninstall.

```
<key>apns</key> 
<array> 
<dict> 
<key>apn</key> 
<string>ABCDE</string> 
<key>username</key>   <<--missing
<string></string>  <<--missing
</dict> 
</array>
```

So, I am looking for any solution, the way to remove the existing mobileconfig by building a app to tackle this abnormal situation. Should you have any ideas or further discussion, it is highly appreciated to share your inputs with me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem as well. I did some combination of this to solve it:

1) manually add the corrected .mobileconfig as a ".stub" file in the directory "/private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles/Library/ConfigurationProfiles" (see the format of other .stub files in the directory)

2) add the PayloadIdentifier from the .mobileconfig file as a  to the   in the "PayloadManifest.plist" file also in the directory "/private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles/Library/ConfigurationProfiles"

Your profile should now show in the "Settings -> General -> Profiles & Device Management." menu

3) Delete your profile using the interactive menu. It will not delete from the menu structure, but it will not give an error either.

4) Delete your ".stub" file from step (1)

5) Maybe also (I can't remember if I did this or not) remove the added entry in "PayloadManifest.plist" (I can't remember if I did this or not)

6) Maybe also (I can't remember if I did this or not) remove the corresponding entry in "ProfileTruth.plist" in "/private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles/Library/ConfigurationProfiles"

7) Delete "/private/var/Managed Preferences/mobile/com.apple.managedCarrier.plist"

8) You will now be able to add (and remove) your corrected mobileconfig file using your regular means

All of this was done on a jailbroken iPhone running 11.3.1